# Oneplus one is not starting as expected

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, fastboot

My OPO(One plus one) with cyanogenmod (last update in August 2016) purchased 2.5+ yrs back, is not starting when it is connected to USB or starting to fastboot mode when it is not connected. It is happening from last 3 weeks only.

When it is in fastboot mode, I connect it to my PC and run command `fastboot continue` to resume the boot and it starts. But I need to do it everytime.

So I have `wipe cache partition` and then `full factory reset`. But I can see that the problem still persist.

I have installed TWRP now. But it din't solve the problem too.

- If I install some custom ROM, would it solve the problem?
- Why fastboot mode comes everytime while there was no update happened
  recently?
- Can it happen due to some hardware issue? (I actually put a cup of hot tea on back of my mobile for a min .... :( )

:: **Update** ::

I have installed LineageOS. But still facing the same issue.